# Play Framework Scala Environment Variables not found

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, playframework-2.0, environment-variables

Sup,

I'm trying to setup environment variables for my project in Play2.4 Scala.
I have set variables in run configuration in Intellij.

What's annoying Scala doesn't seem to see those.

I keep getting errors of configuration not specified for keys I used env variables.

[image]

[image: bug1]

[image: bug2]

When i start the application those shows in the console:

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\bin\java" -Dfile.encoding=UTF8 -DMAIL_PORT=587 -DDB_URI=mongodb://uri -Djline.terminal=none -Dsbt.log.noformat=true -Dsbt.global.base=C:\Users\Haito\AppData\Local\Temp\sbt-global-plugin7stub -Xms512M -Xmx1024M -Xss1M -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -XX:MaxPermSize=256M -classpath C:\Users\Haito\.IntelliJIdea14\config\plugins\Scala\launcher\sbt-launch.jar xsbt.boot.Boot "project root" ~run
```

And the configuration file:

```
mongodb.uri = ${?DB_URI}

play.mailer {
  host=${?MAIL_HOST}
  port=${?MAIL_PORT}
  ssl=false
  tls=true
  user=${?MAIL_USERNAME}
  password=${?MAIL_PASSWD}
  debug=false
  mock=false
}
```

And i keep getting those:

```
Missing configuration key 'mongodb.db'!
```

Of course my problem is not that my mongo driver. My problem is that the config is not being fed with environment variables. Mailer which also uses environment variables for configs. When I paste the actual URI except the `${?DB_URI}` it works.

Build:

```
resolvers += "scalaz-bintray" at "http://dl.bintray.com/scalaz/releases"

resolvers += "Sonatype Snapshots" at "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.reactivemongo" %% "play2-reactivemongo" % "0.11.2.play24"
)

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-mailer" % "3.0.1"
)
```

Comment: You really missing `mongodb.db` in your config. Set it to name of appropriate database at server like `mongodb.db = test`

Comment: That information is encoded in uri.

Comment: @Hallo Did you try to separate it from URL? Probably driver requires it to be configured in separated option

Comment: Also it would be nice if you specify the driver for using with mongo db. For example dependency from `build.sbt` file

Comment: Sure, i have edited my main post. But please acknowledge that my problem is not mongodriver error. My problem is program not seeing environment variables. When i type manually that uri everything is working ok.

Answer (score 6):

This is a [bug in IntelliJ](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/SCL-11175). Setting the "Environment variables" field in the Play run configuration sets system properties, not environment variables.

If you configure environment variables manually somewhere like `.bash_profile` then you can certainly use them in your application.conf like:

```
db.default.url = ${?DB_URL}
```

Comment: I am now on 2023.2 and this problem persists. I know that this is due to how Play is launched, and it specifies a lengthy list of ENV values in command line. I know on Windows that causes the command line buffer to overflow. 

To make the matter worse, the only way to get around this is set env externally and restart the debug or run session. Very inconvenient.

Answer (score 0):

> When i start the application those shows in the console:
>
> ```
>  "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\bin\java" -Dfile.encoding=UTF8 -DMAIL_PORT=587 -DDB_URI=mongodb://uri -Djline.terminal=none -Dsbt.log.noformat=true -Dsbt.global.base=C:\Users\Haito\AppData\Local\Temp\sbt-global-plugin7stub -Xms512M -Xmx1024M -Xss1M -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -XX:MaxPermSize=256M -classpath C:\Users\Haito\.IntelliJIdea14\config\plugins\Scala\launcher\sbt-launch.jar xsbt.boot.Boot "project root" ~run
> ```

`-D` doesn't set environment variables, it sets [JVM system properties](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html). You should be able to set environment variables from the run configuration as well, but a different part of the dialog.

Also, Play's documentation doesn't say it looks at environment variables at all:

> > [As well as the application.conf file, configuration comes from a couple of other places.](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/Configuration)
> >
> > Default settings are loaded from any reference.conf files found on the classpath. Most Play JARs include a reference.conf file with default settings. Settings in application.conf will override settings in reference.conf files.
> >
> > It’s also possible to set configuration using system properties. System properties override application.conf settings.

I.e. passing `-Dmongodb.uri=...` should work.

Later on it does say

> > For substitutions which are not found in the configuration tree, implementations **may** try to resolve them by looking at system environment variables or other external sources of configuration. (More detail on environment variables in a later section.)

but this is just a quote from HOCON README.

You need to looks at the code loading the config to check if it does use one of the methods which include environment variables.

Comment: That explains a lot. But i i have used "Enviroment Variables" box.

Comment: It looks like it should work then. You can try to check if the program sees these environment variables by calling [`System.getenv`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getenv-java.lang.String-)

Comment: Unfortunately sys.env and System.getenv don't return vars i have created in runconfig.

Comment: Also according to Play2 documentation when i do -Dconfig.field=smth it should override it, but it doesnt.

Comment: Have you tried `-Dmongodb.uri`? If so, I don't have any more ideas, unfortunately.

Comment: Yeah, i have tried -Dmongodb.uri, maybe it's just windows security annoyment thing. I heard it has weird issues with envoronment variables.

Answer (score 0):

If your mongodb url contains parameters like `mongodb://xxxxxxxxxx?key=value` then intellij will silently remove that env variable.